# Basic membership system

Tags: information-management, communication

I am looking for recommendations on a basic membership system need to manage the subscriptions for the packages for a commercial website that has these features:

- customize membership types and membership applications
- reminders and renewal notices
- search members
- communication with members via emails

I would prefer that the recommendations are open source and developed by Java or Java technologies; however, any other programming languages are welcome, too.

Comment: I think this question would be improved by [describing your goal (your "user story")](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/352/60). What do you need this software for, how and in which context will you use it?

Comment: any recommendations ?